# Which framework is the most suitable to create a primitive shape drawing app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, quartz-graphics

I am creating a drawing app on iPad which allow the user to create primitive shapes like rectangles, polygons, arcs, etc. This app enables the user to rotate and scale these shapes. 
So, which would you prefer: OpenGL ES or Quartz?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at CoreAnimation (QuartzCore.framework), particularly CAShapeLayer class - it will allow you easily draw shapes + will provides animation effects for many scenarios "out of the box".